# Javascript world map

Tags: javascript, frameworks, dictionary

I'm looking for Javascript framework to create map of the world with ability of painting different coutries in different colors. Thanks!

Comment: That would be a framework with a pretty tight scope (unlikely). I would narrow your googling to canvas solutions and examples that you could modify. Failing that, I'd be surprised if somebody hadn't done something old-school with image maps by now which are generally considered 'ew' but still perfectly legit as far as the browsers are concerned to my knowledge.

Comment: How much do you want to do? Have you heard of OpenLayers? http://openlayers.org/

Answer (score 14):

I would use the great jVectorMap which you can find here:

http://jvectormap.com/

Easy and you can get more maps to import

Answer (score 0):

Better use SVG as its better for graphics. To learn more about it : http://www.w3schools.com/svg/default.asp

You can use free maps provided by wikimedia : http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Blank_SVG_maps_of_the_world

More free maps at : http://speckyboy.com/2010/05/03/25-free-vector-world-maps-ai-eps-and-svg-formats/

Answer (score 0):

You can edit SVG files using Inkscape to create linkable maps quickly.  To get support for older browsers, you can use the Raphael.js library which supports IE 6-8 with VML.  Here is an example to get you started: http://www.raphaeljs.com/world. With a little work, it is even possible to add tooltips, zooming and latitude and longitude markers. See http://simplemaps.com/world for an example of what is possible with Raphael/JavaScript (disclaimer: commercial product that I built).

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: Disclaimer Added.  Thanks for letting me know Andrew.